# How to import a table existing in DB

Tags: google-app-maker

what changed in appmaker?

Some time ago i could do:

> Select a table from the list on the next page and click Import to
>   create your model. You can import any table that's not a join table.

based on information: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#connect_your_app_to_an_existing_custom_google_cloud_sql_database - on Connect your app to an existing custom Google Cloud SQL database

Now this option is not available, only is available:
Create a new table is a SQL database managed by App Maker.

This is not the option i want, i have already all my tables in DB.

The only option i see here is use Calculated SQL or delete all tables from DB and create from the app.

There is any workaround for this and do what i have done until now: using the import option?

Regards

Comment: It seems to be a bug, I've reported it and will share updates here.

Comment: Thank you Pavel. Will wait for your response. 
Regards

Comment: So, it is kinda intended behavior, that maybe will be changed in nearest future. It looks like you have access to App Maker's default instance in your domain and you can modify database directly. Normally, mortal users don't have such privilege and it is very unlikely that a table will magically appear in the database. Afaik, this scenario should work fine for Custom Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes

"With today's release, you no longer can create new Drive Table data models. Your apps can continue to use existing Drive Tables. However, we recommend you upgrade those models to Cloud SQL as soon as possible."